# How to list all the user tables in Sybase along with their row count?

Tags: sybase

I would like to return all the tables and its count next to it. what is the quickest way to go about it?

I know in Oracle, you can do something like below, but not sure about Sybase:

```
declare n number;
begin
   for rec in (select object_name from user_objects where object_type='TABLE')
   loop
     execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||rec.object_name into n;
     dbms_output.put_line (rec.object_name||':'||n);
   end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is the Sybase sql that does the above:

```
select ob.name,st.rowcnt 
from sysobjects ob, systabstats st 
where ob.type="U"  
and st.id=ob.id 
order by ob.name
```

Comment: I am getting multiple entries for many tables by running this query. I think it might be because there are multiple partitions. Can that be the cause?

Comment: Possibly. Look at sysobjects table for more detail.

Comment: Added group by clause to handle multiple entries:  
select ob.name, sum(st.rowcnt) 
from sysobjects ob, systabstats st 
where ob.type="U"  
and st.id=ob.id 
group by ob.name
order by ob.name

Comment: Sybase IQ reacts with `Table 'systabstats' not found` !?!

Comment: This gives an approximation not an exact count.

Comment: Is there a way to filter by database/schema?

Answer (score 11):

It depends on what Sybase product you mean. In my SQL Anywhere (9 and 11), your solution doesn't work, but this works:

```
select table_name, count
from systable
where primary_root<>0 and creator=1
order by 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, systable is deprecated

Comment: I have to use an older version of sybase and this worked perfectly!

Comment: This only displayed tables for me that have DBA as the owner.

Comment: It works in SQL Anywhere 16 as well. I was logged in as non-DBA and it showed all the tables for that user, as I wished.

Answer (score 4):

As there can be multiple entries in `systabstats` table, the query should be:

```
select ob.name, sum(st.rowcnt)
from sysobjects ob, systabstats st 
where ob.type="U"  
and st.id=ob.id 
group by ob.name
order by ob.name
```

Answer (score 3):

If the current user is the creator:

```sql
SELECT table_name, count
  FROM sys.systable
 WHERE creator = user_id()
```

<sup>NOTE: I test this in Sybase ASA 9.</sup>

Comment: Likewise, this only displayed tables for me that have DBA as the owner.

Answer (score 0):

use the below query

```
select name,row_count(db_id(),id) as "Rows"
from sysobjects where type='U' order by 2 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ob.name,st.rowcnt from sysobjects ob, systabstats st  where  b.type='U' 
and st.id=ob.id  and indid=0 order by ob.name
```

Comment: Here I also get "Table 'systabstats' not found"

Comment: Can you add some context to the answer instead of posting code-only answer?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using "SQL Central" with SQL Anywhere 17:

```
SELECT table_name, st.count
FROM systable st 
WHERE table_type = 'BASE'
```